# Trying to parse contents of txt file into a Dictionary in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, csv, nsdictionary

I am trying to parse the contents of a .txt file that contains the following data in this format:

```
93 --- Afghanistan
355 --- Albania
213 --- Algeria
684 --- American Samoa
376 --- Andorra
244 --- Angola
...
1 670 --- North Mariana Islands (Saipan)
...
```

FYI, these are area codes for different countries.

I need to read the data using Swift, and put it into a Dictionary, where the keys are country names, and the values are the area codes.

This is the code that I have thus far:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var dataArray:[String]?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        loadCountryCodes()
    }

    func loadCountryCodes() {
        // Specify the path to the countries list file.
        let pathToFile = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("countrycodes", ofType: "txt")

        if let path = pathToFile {
            // Load the file contents as a string.
            let countriesString = try! String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

            // Append the countries from the string to the dataArray array by breaking them using the line change character.
            dataArray = countriesString.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")


        }
    }

}
```

At the moment, I only know how to read each line in, but what I would like to do, is as I read each line in, add the first string to the dictionary as a value, and the second string that appears after the (---) as the key.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can try something like this, haven't tested the code though so might need some tweaking

```
var dictionary = [String: String]()

for line in dataArray {

    var components = line.components(separatedBy: " --- ")

    dictionary[components[0]] = components[1]
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply.  I tried to run your code, but I get the following error:

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

on your last line:
dictionary[Int(components[0])!] = components[1]

Comment: hmm put a breakpoint on that line and see what values are inside `components` seems like its getting a `nil` inside for some reason

Comment: also make sure in your text file, all the area codes are in fact, numbers.. otherwise you will have to use strings

Comment: Thanks once again.  The issue is that in my txt file, there are some area codes like this: 1 670 --- North Mariana Islands (Saipan), and this is what is causing the problem.  Suggestions?

Comment: ah yes, that wont parse as an int, then can just use strings instead, ill change my answer

Comment: One final thing, in your solution, the area code is the key, and the country is the value.  I need this reversed.

Comment: oh just swap the 0 and 1 around then when adding to the dictionary

Comment: Great!  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the 3rd line of the accepted answer to

```
var components = line.components(separatedBy: " --- ")
```